# Два Ajax-обработчика на одно действие

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

В `wordpress` не будет проблемой, если на ajax навесить два обработчика?
т.е. уже есть один обработчик `wp_ajax_` и `wp_ajax_nopriv_` в плагине, но нужно добавить ещё один в файле `functions.php`.
Что-то не работает, ничего не происходит после добавления

**P.S.**

```
wp_localize_script( 'main', 'localData', array(
    'ajaxURL' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?add_variation_to_cart=1' ),
    'ajaxCart' => wc_get_cart_url(),
    'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
) );
----
    let data = {
        "action" : "variation_add_to_cart",
        "product_id" : product,
        "variation_id" : variation,
        "quantity" : 1,
    };
    $.ajax( {
        method: "POST",
        url: localData.ajaxURL,
        data: data
    })

add_action( 'wp_ajax_variation_add_to_cart', 'my_variation_add_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_variation_add_to_cart', 'my_variation_add_to_cart' );
function my_variation_add_to_cart(){
    PC::debug('test','test');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обработчики добавляются через add_action, а это стандартный механизм, позволяющий добавлять любое число обработчиков. Если надо, можно задать им приоритет.

Раз у вас не работает, значит, ошибка в коде.

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста, добавил код в вопрос. Почему не работает? PC::debug это отладка и вывод сообщений

Comment: Что такое PC::debug, я знаю - это плагин php console )) Из вашего кода непонятно, как описан register_script, и где находится js-код. Кроме того, ajaxURL у вас определен неверно, он не нужен. Используйте переменную url.